# Creating a box with a "dynamic height"

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am looking for a way to create a div with CSS that looks like this graphic:

[image]

The bottom on the right is not white but transparent.

How would that be possible?

Comment: Why do you wanna use this? if it is just red you can just use an image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method #01:**

Use transformed pseudo element i.e `:before` or `:after`.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

div:before {
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  position: absolute;
  background: brown;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 40%;
  content: '';
  right: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Method #02:**

Use css3 `linear-gradient`.

```
background: linear-gradient(175deg, brown 60%, transparent 60%);
```

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, brown 60%, transparent 60%);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transformations.  Here is an example.

```css
#me {
  margin-left:-100px;
  margin-top:-100px;
  width:150%; height:200px;
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:#8B1414;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
#wrapper {
  min-height:200px; background-color:#000; padding:20px; overflow:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="me">asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can change the background of #wrapper, i show it as black to prove with clarity that the maroon parallelogram is transparent outside its boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear-gradient background. This would work like this:

```
<div class="box">
</div>

.box {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, red 50%)
}
```

Or you could use CSS transform to rotate the box. How to do this you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if the width is constant, so I'll assume it is not (responsive design?) and I also assume, that you want to have a constant angle independently on the width of the `<div></div>`.

To achieve this you will, however need to use SASS with some math-enhancing libraries (ie. [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), [Sassy-Math](https://github.com/at-import/Sassy-math)). These will give you the `pow()`, `sqrt()`, and `sin()` functions necessary for the Pythagorean calculations.

Here is the basic function that will calculate the height of the tilted edge depending on the angle you want the tilt to take.

```
@function get-tilted-height($angle) {
  $a: (100% / 1%);
  $A: (90deg - $angle);
  $c: ($a / sin($A));
  $b: sqrt(pow($c, 2) - pow($a, 2));

  @return (abs($b) * 1%);
}
```

Now for the SASS mixin.

```
@mixin tilted($angle, $color, $position: 'top', $pseudo: 'before') {
  $height: get-tilted-height($angle);

  position: relative;
  background-color: $color;

  &::#{$pseudo} {
    content: '';
    padding-top: $height;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    @if ($position == 'top') {
      bottom: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient($angle, $color 50%, transparent 50%);
    } @else {
      top: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient($angle, transparent 50%, $color 50%);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you just include the mixin in your code like this:

```
.container {
  @include tilted(3deg, rgb(255, 255, 255), bottom);
  padding: 0 1em;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1em 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}
```

Note the `position: relative` that the container aquires, so then we can position the `::after` pseudo-element absolutely. Also the height of the tilt is defined by `padding-top` as you can't rely on `height` that is computed from the parents height.

My credit goes to [Hugo Giraudel](https://www.sitepoint.com/author/hgiraudel/) and his brilliant article on [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/tilted-angles-in-sass/), which I recommend you to read to find out more details. And here is a link to CodePen where you can see it in action: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/dppJzX

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way.

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  left:-30px;
  width:150px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#8D120D;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  
  </div>
</div>
```